# StructureMap Constructor arguments without Concrete type or args by instance name

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap, constructor-injection

I did read other answers but none of them fully fit, so please bear with me
Background pseudo code (disregard SM version)

```
public interface IFilter() {}

public class A: IFilter {}
public class B: IFilter {}
public class C: IFilter {}
public class D: IFilter {}


public interface IProcessor()
{
}

public Processor(List<IFilter> filters) //List, IEnumerbale, Array doesn't matter 
{
}

ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
    x.Scan(scanner =>
    {
        ...
        scanner.AddAllTypesOf<IFilter>().NameBy(type => type.Name);
    });
});
```

How to configure SM to use instance "B" and "C" for default? I can configure like this but I don't want to:

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
{
    var filters = new List<IFilter>();
    filters.Add(ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<IFilter>("B")); //I don't like create instance before concrete use
    filters.Add(ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<IFilter>("C"));
    x.For<IProcessor>().Use(new Processor(filters)); //this works, but I don't like to use concrete type, what if not accessible?
});
```

Is there a way to configure it this way (pseudo)

```
x.For<IProcessor>().Ctor<List<IFilter>>().ByInstanceName(new[] {"B","C"})
//or assuming only one concrete type is defined for IProcessor
x.For<IProcessor>().Named("Alpha").Ctor<List<IFilter>>().ByInstanceName(new[] {"B","C"});
x.For<IProcessor>().Named("Beta").Ctor<List<IFilter>>().ByInstanceName(new[] {"A","D"});
```

or generally any other way without using concrete type in code reference?
I understand that IProcessor may have multiple instances, but is there really no way for SM to match Ctor signature and wire any IProcessor instance using named instances when match?

And if concrete type must be used then at least still use instance name for ctor and not to create list

```
x.For<IProcessor>().Use(new Processor()).WithCtorInstanceByName("B","C");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax you're looking for is:

```
For<IProcessor>().Use<Processor>().EnumerableOf<IFilter>().Contains(_ => {
    _.TheInstanceNamed("A");                        
    _.TheInstanceNamed("A"); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Where did you find the documentation about it? Self discovered?

Comment: @PawelCioch Self-discovered, in the sense that he's the creator of StructureMap :D